# customized map function with multiple variable input in pyspark return wrong results

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, parallel-processing, pyspark

As a part of my project, I am trying to implement parallelized normalization operation on a bulk of matrice by using a map function with the matrix to processed and vectors encapsulating min and max value of each dimension as input variables. The codes are listed below:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def cf(A,MinValues,MaxValues):
   print("Result is ##################",A=(A-MinValues)/(MaxValues-MinValues))
   A=(A-MinValues)/(MaxValues-MinValues)
   return A

if __name__=='__main__':
   AMatrix=np.matrix([[1,5,9],[4,8,3],[7,2,6]])
   MinMatrix=np.matrix([1,2,3])
   MaxMatrix=np.matrix([7,8,9])
   ........
   sc.parallelize(AMatrix).map(partial(cf,MinValues=MinMatrix,MaxValues=MaxMatrix)).collect()
```

After I run the code above, it will display correct answers on the terminal via print operation during the processing, however it will always display [[None],[None],[None]] by the end, which means that (I guess) after the map() operation the spark can only collect a list include [None] elements.

Can guru here possibly tell me what happened here please? what is the right way to implement the function?

Great in advance

Comment: Since the code you posted doesn't include any `print()` - it's a bit difficult to say where it's coming from...

Comment: it means that (I guess) after the map() operation the spark can only collect a list include [None] elements.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code (python 2.7):

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def cf(A,MinValues,MaxValues):
    #print "Result is " + str((A-MinValues)/(MaxValues-MinValues))
    A=(A-MinValues)/(MaxValues-MinValues)
    return A


AMatrix=np.matrix([[1,5,9],[4,8,3],[7,2,6]])
MinMatrix=np.matrix([1,2,3])
MaxMatrix=np.matrix([7,8,9])

print sc.parallelize(AMatrix).map(partial(cf,MinValues=MinMatrix,MaxValues=MaxMatrix)).collect()
```

And this is the result:

```
[matrix([[0, 0, 1]]), matrix([[0, 1, 0]]), matrix([[1, 0, 0]])]
```

I can't see the problem..